# ROS dynamic_reconfigure::Client::setConfiguration could not set configuration

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm writing a simple client dynamic_reconfigure.If the  `batch_size` is equal to 20, then client should reset one parameter in config to 0.0. However, while running the node, the node throws the error  `[ WARN] [1657666570.407288065]: Could not set configuration`. Below is my code.

```
void adjuster_callback(const hc::HcNodeConfig& data) {
   std::cout << "this is a callback function" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int batch_size = 0;
    ros::init(argc, argv, "adjuster");
    hc::HcNodeConfig config;
    dynamic_reconfigure::Client<hc::HcNodeConfig> client("hc", adjuster_callback);
    ros::Duration d(2);
    client.getDefaultConfiguration(config, d);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
    while (ros::ok()) {
        batch_size += 1;
        if (batch_size == 10) {
            config.angle = 0.0;
            client.setConfiguration(config);
            batch_size = 0;
        }
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403710/ros-dynamic_reconfigure::client::setconfiguration-could-not-set-configuration/) by [hck007](https://answers.ros.org/users/96442/hck007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2022-07-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RyanChen.YLC](https://answers.ros.org/users/99089/ryanchen.ylc/) on 2022-07-12**:
I met this warning once, and I found the reason coming from the server name not matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you are confused about the difference between `dynamic_reconfigure::Server` and `dynamic_reconfigure::Client` (and the wiki page could use some improvement describing this.)

You should use Server to create a dynamic parameter, which typically is a parameter in the namespace of the current ros node. Creating the server instance will cause a ros service named ".../set_parameters" to be created.

You use Client to set or monitor a dynamic parameter for some *other* ros node. Client assumes the set_parameters service has already been created by that other ros node.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2